# NetBeans exit error code value -1.073.741.819 in C

Tags: c, netbeans, runtime-error

I have a script on NetBeans that asks for user input. Because the "console type" internal terminal was giving me an error I changed the console to standard output.

It works with a common simple code but when I try to run it on my actual code it returns the error "RUN FAILED (exit value -1.073.741.819, total time: 79ms)" right after it appears the message before the input.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int product, price, n_product, sum, num, canti, total;
    printf("What's the number of products? ");
    scanf( "%d", &n_product );
    num=1;
    sum=0;
    while(num<=n_product) {
      printf("What was the product? ");
      scanf( "%s", product );
      printf("What was the unit price? ");
      scanf( "%d", &price );
      printf("How much did you buy? ");
      scanf( "%d", &canti );
      total=price*canti;
      sum=sum+total;
      num++;
     }

    printf("Total is %n", sum);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have searched the error but no results appear so I don't really know what is wrong with it.

There isn't a single variable on the code which is not declared. Since it stops right after the first `printf` I have considered that the error may be on the `scanf` but I don't know.

EDIT:

I changed the code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int price, n_product, sum, num, canti, total;
    char product[20];
    printf("What's the number of products? ");
    scanf( "%d", &n_product );
    num=1;
    sum=0;
    while(num<=n_product) {
      printf("What was the product? ");
      scanf( "%19s", product );
      printf("What was the unit price? ");
      scanf( "%d", &price );
      printf("How much did you buy? ");
      scanf( "%d", &canti );
      total=price*canti;
      sum=sum+total;
      num++;
     }

    printf("Total is %d", sum);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Now external terminal gives me no error but I can't input at all and just let me close it

Comment: Write the full _relevant_ code.  i.e. Only code that is likely to be related to error condition you are asking about.  The code snippet should be compilable, so it can be run by those attempting to help.  ( Provide a  [mcve] )

Comment: I wrote everything since I just started with C and idk what is relevant for this. Since it didn't pass that point I thought that was the relevant part.

Comment: Are you certain you do not have any configuration problems in your _[NetBeans environment](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/quickstart.html)_?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure because the other projects weren't giving me any error on anything so maybe it was the configuration of this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that NetBeans is kinda broken for absolutely no reason and all I needed to do was to try this code on another file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int product,num,sum, price, canti, total;
    char name[20];
    puts("What's the number of products? ");
    scanf( "%d", &product );
    num=1;
    sum=0;

    while(num<=product) {
        puts("What's the product name? ");
        scanf("%19s", name);
        puts("What's the unit price? ");
        scanf( "%d", &price );
        puts("How much did you buy? ");
        scanf( "%d", &canti );
        total=price*canti;
        sum=sum + total;
        num++;
    }

    printf("We've bought %d", sum);
}
```

Still can't understand why but that is how I fixed it. And no, it doesn't work on the same file I was trying to edit, I had to make a new one so it would work.

Comment: I removed my comment.  If these changes solved your problem, (no matter how mysteriously) then it is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `product` variable is declared as an `int`, however when you attempt to input a value for it you do this:

```
scanf( "%s", product );
```

This *would* be correct if `product` was defined as a character array, however it is not.  This instead takes the current value of `product` (which is unknown because it is uninitialized) and passes it to `scanf`, which interprets it as a pointer to a character array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a crash.

Change the type of `product` to a character array, and modify the call to `scanf` to tell it the size of that array:

```
char product[20];
...
scanf("%19s", product);
```

That's the first problem.  The second one is here:

```
printf("Total is %n", sum);
```

The `%n` format specifier is used to store the total number of characters printed so far and expects a `int *` argument.  Because you instead pass in an `int`, this causes the same problem as before.

Since you presumably want to print the value of `sum`, you should instead use the `%d` format specifier:

```
printf("Total is %d", sum);
```

Comment: @Spina97 See my edit.  The `printf` at the end was also incorrect.

Comment: Given that your code snippet appears to be solid, the problem could be on the NetBeans side.